# Get children specific value and update when there is a change Firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database. I would like to get only the values highlighted red. When there is a new child with same value `profile_picture:`, i would like to update the list as well.

[image]

I manage to get all the values but i still can't figure out how to get only  `profile_picture:` value from every child.

```js
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getDatabase();
    const email = ref(db, 'users/');
    onValue(email, (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    })
```

OUTPUT

```
[
null,
{
    "email": "Test_1_Email",
    "profile_picture": "Test_1_URL",
    "username": "Test_1"
},
{
    "email": "Test_2_Email",
    "profile_picture": "Test_2_URL",
    "username": "Test_2"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done by a single listener. `ref(db, 'users/')` will return the whole `/users` node. If you just want to listen for `profile_picture` then you'll have to add a listener for every user's `profile_picture` like this:

```
const userIds = ["u1", "u2"]

userIds.forEach(user => {
  const email = ref(db, 'users/' + user);
  onValue(email, (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  })
})
```

I had hard-coded the UIDs here for example but you'll need to know the user IDs beforehand to use this.

Alternatively, you can just store the frequently accessed information such as user name and picture in a separate node.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this and still learning it. What if the userIds is dynamic and i dont know userid numbers.

Comment: @sadiqali yes, I've updated my answer. It's more like you'll have to query the UIDs first. If you just need to listen to profile picture then you can store the URLs in a separate node.

Comment: Yeah, i think separate node might be the best way to go.